# Circumstellar Habitable Zone of an Orange Dwarf

Tags: science-based, space

I want to create a system orbiting an [Orange Dwarf star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-type_main-sequence_star), approximately 0.5 M☉.

I've a 5-planet system, one of which needs to be within the habitable zone of this star; this planet will be 2 M⊕

I know the formula for this is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$, but I'm unsure where exactly that would place my habitable planet and whether or not this means my habitable planet would be tidally locked.

So my question is thus; **"Please calculate the habitable zone for my system above and let me know if the habitable planet would be tidally locked."**

I would appreciate the answer to be in AU.

Comment: You might also try asking on [astronomy.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While many people continue to assume tidal locking, I’d like to point out that a spin-orbit resonance that’s an *odd* half multiple is a [more stable case](http://www.seti.org/weeky-lecture/patterns-sunlight-extra-solar-planets). For example, [our own planet Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)#Spin.E2.80.93orbit_resonance).

To make a long story short, if there is another *large* planet farther out, you can expect this situation.

For your main question, I asked Google for `habitable zone calculator` and found [this page](http://depts.washington.edu/naivpl/sites/default/files/hz.shtml) and several others.

Comment: I just did a search of my own and i got 2 sites with different answers in them, I'm not sure which one to believe. (Oh and both agree my planet would be tidally locked based on a one-planet system)

Comment: Are the answers far apart? Do they document the models and methods used?  Does one have more inputs or more precision of input than the other?

Comment: The one you suggested is asking for luminosity and effective temperature in Kelvin, whereas the other one just asks for Stellar Mass and Planet distance

Comment: and the second seems to make out that the planet would be tidally locked whereas the first doesn't seem to indicate one way or the other

Comment: So you had to convert your stated mass to temperature. Maybe different than what the other page had built in?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I got an estimated answer from the first at between 0.203 AU and 0.389 AU when plugging in the numbers from the second

Comment: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/habitablezones/animations/stellarHabitableZone.html - This one, to be precise was the second

Comment: Tidal locking: see my link in the answer. The presence of *other planets* will drive eccentricity which will cause Mercury-like resonance rather than 1:1 locking.

Comment: Thanks. I'll end this off now by accepting your answer and moving discussion to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46534/discussion-between-raisus-and-jdlugosz).

Answer (score 2):

This formula for calculating the habitable zone can be found [here](http://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/H/habzone.html)

> Calculating the HZ in the simplest case
>
> If all of the complicating factors discussed above are ignored and the
> habitable zone is defined simply as the distance from a star where the
> effective temperature is in the range 0° to 100°C then it is
> straightforward to calculate the radii of the HZ's inner and outer
> bounds. The relevant formula is:
>
> L = 4π r 2σT 4
>
> where L is the star's luminosity, r is the distance from the center of
> the star, σ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant (= 5.67 × 10-8 W m-2
> K-1), and T is the effective temperature (in kelvin). For the Sun,
> this yields a range for the HZ of 0.7 to 1.5 AU. The HZ range for
> other stars can then be calculated easily since, from the above
> formula:
>
> Lstar/Lsun = rstar2/rsun2
>
> In the case of Vega, Lstar/Lsun = 53, which gives a range for HZ of
> 5.1 to 10.9 AU. In the case of Kapteyn's Star, Lstar/Lsun = 0.004 and the corresponding HZ range is 0.044 to 0.095 AU.

This is good for a rule of thumb way of calculating habitable zones. It can be used in conjugate with some of the more fancy habitable zone calculators on the internet.

Comment: You still need to find the Luminosity for a particular mass main-sequence star.

Comment: Of course. While this is reasonably easy for known stars, when it comes to worldbuilding there should be ball park figures for stars of a given Hertzsprung-Russell class and with a given mass. Our friends at Astronomy SE should be able to help too.